# Visual Studio 2022 - AWS Toolkit does not support Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, aws-step-functions

There is support for Step Function in Visual Studio Code using AWS Toolkit. I could not find anything similar for Visual Studio 2022.

Is there any way for having Step Functions in Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 2):

AWS Step Functions is not supported in the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio today. The toolkit's team is interested in learning more about your use case and what features would add value to your workflow. Please create an issue on Github at https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-visual-studio/issues to share any relevant details.

Comment: The way we develop and deploy lambda functions from Visual Studio. Similarly, I want to develop and deploy step functions from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need AWS Toolkit to code logic using **AWS SDK for .NET v3**. What you need to do is to install the required .NET Assemblies using NuGET in Visual Studio. Install **AWSSDK.StepFunctions** - as shown here:

[image]

Install **AWSSDK.Core** too.

Then you can write a .NET APP that uses the .NET Step Functions Service Client.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/StepFunctions/TStepFunctionsClient.html

Comment: Basically, I have created the step function using AWS console. Now I need to add it to source code. Similar to the way we add Lambda function project where we add code, deploy and commit from Visual Studio.